# Deduction of auto make the compiler generate defaults constructors

Tags: c++

Consider this code, wrote with the only purpose of an exercise:

```
class Param {
 private:
  struct Foo{  
    int bar;
  };
  
public:
  Foo foo;
};

int main()
{
  Param p;
  p.foo.bar = 5;
}
```

Generate this intermediate code with [cppInsight](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGNzdGRpbz4KCmNsYXNzIFBhcmFtIHsKIHByaXZhdGU6CiAgc3RydWN0IEZvb3sgIAogICAgaW50IGJhcjsKICB9OwogIApwdWJsaWM6CiAgRm9vIGZvbzsKfTsKCmludCBtYWluKCkKewogIFBhcmFtIHA7CiAgcC5mb28uYmFyID0gNTsKfQ==&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0):

```
#include <cstdio>

class Param
{
  
  private: 
  struct Foo
  {
    int bar;
    // inline Foo() noexcept = default;
  };
  
  
  public: 
  Foo foo;
  // inline Param() noexcept = default;
};



int main()
{
  Param p = Param();
  p.foo.bar = 5;
  return 0;
}
```

Everything look fine, Param can be instantiated, bar can be modified but Param::Foo cannot be instantiated. adding a

```
int main()
{
  Param p;
  p.foo.bar = 5;
  Param::Foo f = p.foo; // compile error
}
```

lead to a compiler error as expected. BUT if I try with a deduction of auto

```
int main()
{
  Param p;
  p.foo.bar = 5;
  auto f = p.foo; // it works!
}
```

it does works!

Checking with cppInsight the new generate code look like [this](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGNzdGRpbz4KCmNsYXNzIFBhcmFtIHsKIHByaXZhdGU6CiAgc3RydWN0IEZvb3sgIAogICAgaW50IGJhcjsKICB9OwogIApwdWJsaWM6CiAgRm9vIGZvbzsKfTsKCmludCBtYWluKCkKewogIFBhcmFtIHA7CiAgcC5mb28uYmFyID0gNTsKICAvL1BhcmFtOjpGb28gZiA9IHAuZm9vOwogIGF1dG8gZiA9IHAuZm9vOwp9&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0):

```
#include <cstdio>

class Param
{
  
  private: 
  struct Foo
  {
    int bar;
    // inline Foo() noexcept = default;
    // inline constexpr Foo(const Foo &) noexcept = default;
  };
  
  
  public: 
  Foo foo;
  // inline Param() noexcept = default;
};

int main()
{
  Param p = Param();
  p.foo.bar = 5;
  Param::Foo f = Param::Foo(p.foo);
  return 0;
}
```

Using the deduction with auto make the compiler generate the default copy constructor and actually be instantiated.

Could someone explain why this behaviour is happening?

Comment: I would say that is an artifact of cppinsight. The copy constructor was available even without auto, but cppinsigts only show them if they are used.

Comment: As designed.  If you want to "lock down" Foo make the constructors private, and make Param a friend.

Comment: @Eljay I'm aware it's not a correct design, I was just confused of the different behaviour using auto

Comment: I meant "as designed" in the sense of "that is how C++ `auto` was intentionally designed".  Whether or not C++'s design is correct or not is moot, because that ship has sailed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making `Param::Foo` private means that you can't access it via this name. The C++ standard says that in chapter 11.9 ("Member access control") [[C++20 draft N4860 PDF](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf)]:

> A member of a class can be
>
> — private; that is, its **name** can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared.

and

> [Note: Access to members and base classes is controlled, not their visibility (6.4.10). Names of members
> are still visible, and implicit conversions to base classes are still considered, when those members and base
> classes are inaccessible. — end note]

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

`auto` doesn't use that name.

This is sometimes done on purpose, e.g. for iterators of containers. That way you can use the iterator with `auto` only. The advantage is that the implementation of the container can change the iterator at a later point in time without breaking your code (because you would need to switch to a new name).